# How to remove filter in data extraction from a web page in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have an R script in which I extract data from a web page, the script I have runs correctly but I want to remove the filter that has the Instrument column or that brings me the data from:

the page from which I extract the data looks like this and has a filter in the instrument column

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9zPV.png)

#The script is as follows:

```
library(rvest)


urls.colombia.compra <- paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=", 
                               0:11, 
                               "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Microsoft&date_to_=%20&date_from_=")


base.colombia.compra <- purrr::map_df(urls.colombia.compra, ~.x %>% read_html() %>% html_table)

base.colombia.compra
```

How can I edit the R script to remove or apply filters to it?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: In the message leave an image link of how the page from which I extract the data looks, it is a table of 6 columns, one of those columns is called Instrument and it has a filter that is reflected in the url like this "tool = IAD % 20Software% 20I% 20-% 20Microsoft ", I would like to remove it to see all the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove that and make a successful request which returns all logs. It is not an optional query string param and there is no *all* parameter value that I could easily spot. Presumably it is used to query a backend database.

You have to pass one of the dropdown values. So, I would scrape those `instrumento` dropdown values, then generate all the combinations which include urls with each of those instrumentos and page numbers etc.